# Virtual Display with Apple Remote Desktop

Tags: mac, remote-desktop, osx-lion, remote-control

I have a MacMini which uses a TV as display (it's my media center) and a MacBook, both running OSX Lion. I bought Apple Remote Desktop and set it up. I can connect to the MacMini with my laptop (using the same user that is logged in on the MacMini) with the virtual display option and it works just fine *except* two things:

1. I'd like to have a secondary display on the remote connection and not the same one that's used on the TV (so I can do stuff on the MacMini while a movie is running). Ideally it would behave just like a 2nd display.
2. The resolution should be different on the remote connection (my laptop's display is smaller than 1080...). This probably gets solved with #1.

I know that I could connect with a different user and set the permissions accordingly (and that's what I'll do if I can't find a better solution) but it would be way better if I could use the same user (no hassle with permissions, running applications etc.).

Any hints much appreciated!